# Python datetime weekday strftime() vs weekday()

Tags: python, datetime, dataframe, strftime, weekday

Have a pandas dataframe df, in order to get weekday from the date column, I did:

```
df_raw['DayOfWeek'] = df_raw[str_date_colname].dt.strftime('%w')
```

It returns weekday as a decimal number, where 0 is Sunday and 6 is Saturday. However, I want to get 0 is Monday and 6 is Sunday. So I did:

```
df_raw['DayOfWeek'] = df_raw[str_date_colname].dt.weekday()
```

But it returns: `'Series' object is not callable`

May I know why? I think both `strftime()` and `weekday()`are callable in datetime objects: https://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html

Comment: Could you print value and type of `df_raw[str_date_colname].dt`?

Comment: @Shpionus it's <class 'pandas.tseries.common.DatetimeProperties'>

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If `df` is a Pandas DataFrame, then `df['date']` is a Series. If `df['date']` contains datetimes (in particular, if the dtype is `datetime64[ns]`s) then the Series will have a [`.dt` accessor](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/basics.html#dt-accessor).

```
In [12]: type(df['date'])
Out[12]: pandas.core.series.Series

In [13]: type(df['date'].dt)
Out[13]: pandas.tseries.common.DatetimeProperties
```

The `DatetimeProperties` object returned by `df['date'].dt` has a `weekday` [*property*](https://docs.python.org/2/howto/descriptor.html#properties) (not a method). Properties are accessed without parentheses, so simply use `df['date'].dt.weekday` rather than `df['date'].dt.weekday()`.

---

For example,

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'date': pd.date_range('2000-1-1', periods=7)})
df['dow'] = df['date'].dt.strftime('%w')
df['dow2'] = df['date'].dt.weekday
df['dow3'] = df['date'].dt.strftime('%a')
```

yields

```
        date dow  dow2 dow3
0 2000-01-01   6     5  Sat
1 2000-01-02   0     6  Sun
2 2000-01-03   1     0  Mon
3 2000-01-04   2     1  Tue
4 2000-01-05   3     2  Wed
5 2000-01-06   4     3  Thu
6 2000-01-07   5     4  Fri
```

---

It's commonly said that "Everything in Python is an object". Therefore it's very important to understand the *type* of each object since that determines what methods and attributes that object will have. [The documentation you linked to](https://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html), shows the methods available for `datetime.datetime` objects. Since `df['date'].dt` is a `pandas.tseries.common.DatetimeProperties` object, it has different attributes.

---

Whenever you see an error message of the form

```
blahblah object is not callable
```

Python is telling you it found an object, `obj`, of type `blahblah` followed by
parentheses -- i.e. it encountered `obj(...)` where `type(obj)` is
`blahblah`. The parentheses cause Python to call the object. Thus, it is
complaining that `obj` is not callable.

So to hunt down the source of the problem in the future, find the line mentioned
in the full traceback error message and look for parentheses.

```
df_raw['DayOfWeek'] = df_raw[str_date_colname].dt.weekday()
```

The object *immediately in front of those parentheses* should be of type `blahblah`. 
For example, `df_raw[str_date_colname].dt.weekday` is of type `Series`.
You'll then know the source of the problem. Once you know that `df_raw[str_date_colname].dt.weekday` is a Series, you'll be curious to see what its values are, and then you'll discover it is already the values you are looking for.